# RequestBody is not mapped to the object

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

Requestbody is not getting mapped to the Object that i used here.  All the fields in PaymentRequest are coming as null. I see annotations and mapings everything seems to be correct.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pay")
public class PaymentServiceAPIImpl {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response submitPaymentRequest(@RequestBody PaymentRequest paymentRequest) {
        System.out.println(paymentRequest.getClientId()); // here I am getting all the fields are null
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}    

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "payment_request", namespace = "http://www.abc-services.com/payment_request", propOrder = { "currencyCode", "clientId" })
public class PaymentRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "currency_code")
    protected String currencyCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "client_id")
    protected String clientId;

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }
    public void setCurrencyCode(String value) {
        this.currencyCode = value;
    }
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }
    public void setClientId(String value) {
        this.clientId = value;
    }
}
```

Here is the request

```
 curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/pay/request \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: fead689c-239-284bb2116ae2' \
  -d '{
    "payment_token": {
        "client_id": "cyber",
        "currency_code": "USD"
    }
}'
```

getting paymentrequest  like this into the controller:

```
PaymentRequest {
     clientId: null,
     cardType: null,
     cardIssuer: null
 }
```

Any pointers why the request is not mapped to the PaymentRequest?

Comment: Are you using an XML ObjectMapper? Why are you using java.xml annotations?

Comment: You are posting application/json, but your model is defining XML mapping.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is common for Spring MVC to use a mapping implementation that can use XML annotations to define JSON property names, allowing code to co-support JSON and XML with minimal definition, hence allowing the client to decide whether they prefer JSON or XML through the use of `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers.

Answer (score 3):

You code doesn't map the data because the JSON is an object with a single property named `payment_token`, and you parameter type `PaymentRequest` doesn't have a property of that name.

Either change payload to:

```
{
    "client_id": "cyber",
    "currency_code": "USD"
}
```

Or change parameter type to use this class instead:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "payment_wrapper", namespace = "http://www.abc-services.com/payment_wrapper", propOrder = { "paymentToken" })
public class PaymentWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name = "payment_token")
    protected PaymentRequest paymentToken;

    public PaymentRequest getPaymentToken() {
        return paymentToken;
    }
    public void setPaymentToken(PaymentRequest value) {
        this.paymentToken = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request in JSON but Parameter is XML.
Something change:

```
 curl -X POST \
 http://localhost:8080/pay/request \
 -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'Postman-Token: fead689c-239-284bb2116ae2' \
 -d '{
        "clientId": "cyber",
        "currencyCode": "USD"
    }'

public class PaymentRequest {
    protected String currencyCode;
    protected String clientId;

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }
    public void setCurrencyCode(String value) {
        this.currencyCode = value;
    }
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }
    public void setClientId(String value) {
        this.clientId = value;
    }
}
```